# Filter pandas dataframe by complex dynamic conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I need to filter down a pandas dataframe based on conditions for multiple columns. I got these conditions from a dict config file like this:

```
config = {
 "PLANT_ID": ["KD"],
 "CO_CD": ["V", "R"]
 }
```

What this means is that I need to filter down the dataset like:
if (PLANT_ID starts with KD) or (CO_CD startswith V or R) then I should keep that record.
There can be more than 2 columns specified, and more than 2 strings in the list.

I know I can use startswith and convert the list to tuples like this:

```
df.PLANT_ID.str.startswith(tuple(config['PLANT_ID']))
```

But I somehow need to write this condition to dynamically pick the column names from the config dict.

Comment: Your question lacks sufficient detail. for us to help resolve Please edit your question to showwhat you have tried so far, and a minimal reproducible example. See  [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Can you provide an example DataFrame with a minimal dataset and the matching expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can craft a regex for each item in your initial dictionary, then `apply` it using `str.startswith` to each column and aggregate with `any`:

```
import re
regex = {k: "|".join(map(re.escape, l)) for k,l in config.items()}

m = df[list(config)].apply(lambda c: c.str.startswith(regex[c.name])).any(1)

df2 = df[m]
```